# GDI+ Tearing! VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, gdi+

I have problem with the Graphic object. I have a loop which goes through some array and it gets the images from them and It draws them on a picture box. Every thing is fine but When I try to resize or draw another thing which is a little bit more heavy, Every thing start flashing Like when they're painting. I know it's too heavy to draw all that damn things ! but is there any way to avoid tearing?

Thanks.

**Edit:**

my code:

```
graphic.Clear(frmmain.Workspace.BackColor)
For i = 0 To mObjectsList.Count - 1
  graphic.DrawImage(mObjectsList(i).oGraphic, mObjectsList(i).oX, mObjectsList(i).oY, mObjectsList(i).oWidth, mObjectsList(i).oHeight)
Next
```

Comment: Any code you would like to share with us to reinforce your description as right now you talk about some *GDI+ tearing* which makes little sense to me?

Comment: OK, now that you have shown some code I have a couple of question: 1. What is `graphic` and how are you fetching a reference to it? 2. What is the size of the `mObjectsList` list? 3. Where is this code being executed?

Comment: Alright. `graphic` is a variable which I created it from my picturebox `Graphic` object. `mObjectsList` is too big ! I mean it can store how many items you want. The code executed in Paint event of picturebox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> graphic is a variable which I created it from my picturebox Graphic object

A picturebox doesn't have a Graphic object.  Do *not* use its CreateGraphics() method.  Whatever you draw through that stays on the screen for only a fraction of a second, barely making a blip. Use e.Graphics in the Paint event handler instead.  That draws into the double-buffered bitmap.  PictureBox always has its DoubleBuffered property set to true.  That bitmap gets drawn when the Paint event completes.  Which is why your objects flicker, they get overdrawn again by that bitmap.

Comment: You again! Thanks. Yeah I was meaning the CreateGraphic method not the object. BTW I want to use e.Graphic in another function, I got it by a variable but the first code which runs with this variable gives error. I don't know, May I used it in a bad way. I defined a public variable and in the paint I assigned it like this **mWorkspaceGraphic = e.Graphics** and Then at the runtime,  first code **mWorkspaceGraphic.Clear(...)** gave me error `Parameter is not valid`.

Comment: Well, sure, three dots is not a valid argument.  Not sure how you expect me to reverse-engineer the exception from that, I could only guess at CreateGraphics.  Simply pass e.Graphics as an argument to any method that wants to do any drawing.  Storing it in a variable is a Bad Idea, it is only valid while the Paint event runs.  Trying to use it after that is going to kaboom.  Re-iterating: only draw in the paint event.  If you have a reason to redraw something then call the control's Invalidate() method.  Which makes the Paint event run.  Eventually.

Comment: Sorry, About the three dots its just `frmmain.Workspace.BackColor`. I know what you're saying but I want to be able to call my draw function from everywhere. In this way I should just use the Paint event to get the `e.Graphics`. So, any solution?

Comment: Re-iterating again: you can call Invalidate() from everywhere.  It means "what the user sees right now is not up to date, it ought to be repainted".  And Windows eventually complies with "nothing more important needs to be done right now, heck, let's generate the Paint event".  Which is no different from "the user restored the window" or "the user is dragging another window across yours".  Which generates Paint events triggered by the window manager.  You need to write your code so that the Paint event faithfully reproduces the scene in all those cases.

Comment: I think you didn't get my point. I was saying If I want to use e.Graphics I should give it to my function like this `drawObjects(e.Graphics)` but I just can get the e.Graphics In paint event and If I want to call my drawObject from a command button click event for example, I can't use `drawObjects(e.Graphics)` cuz I need e.Graphics and It's in the paint event not in here. So what should I do? I just want to get e.Graphics.

Comment: Unfortunately you don't get my point.  What you want is just not the way Windows works.  Good luck with it.